# Dar formato a fecha en MySql

Tags: mysql

Al ejecutar la siguiente sentencia, ocurre el error: `Unabled to convert Date/time`. Intento mostrar la información que trae este query en un `DataGridView`.

```
SELECT codigo, nombre, marca, precio, CONVERT(fechaexpira, DATE)
FROM productos
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utiliza la función [**`DATE_FORMAT`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) para convertir una columna de tipo `DATE` o `TIME`<sup>1</sup> a *string*. Es decir (por ejemplo):

```
SELECT codigo,
       nombre,
       marca,
       precio, 
       DATE_FORMAT(fechaexpira, '%d/%m/%Y') 
  FROM productos
```

donde:

```
+----+------------------------------------+
| %d | Day of the month, numeric (00..31) |
| %m | Month, numeric (00..12)            |
| %Y | Year, numeric, four digits         |
+----+------------------------------------+
```

---

*Notas*

1. Véase [*Date and Time Types*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html).

Comment: la %s significa día?

Comment: Debe ser `%d`. ¡Gracias por la nota!

Answer (score 2):

Vamos por partes, con este par de líneas se adquiere la idea base:

```
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%W, %M %e, %Y @ %h:%i %p')
#yields 'Sundía, September 20, 2008 @ 12:45 PM'
```

Ahora:

```
Especificador   Descripción
%a  Apreviación para el nombre del día (Lun...Dom)
%b  Apreviación para el nombre del mes (Ene...Dic)
%c  Mes, numérico (0..12)
%D  Día del mes con sufijo inglés (0th, 1st, 2nd, 3rd, …)
%d  Día del mes, numérico (00..31)
%e  Día del mes, numérico (0..31)
%f  MicroSegundos (000000..999999)
%H  Hora (00..23)
%h  Hora (01..12)
%I  Hora (01..12)
%i  Minutos, numérico (00..59)
%j  Día del año (001..366)
%k  Hora (0..23)
%l  Hora (1..12)
%M  Nombre del mes (Enero...Diciembre)
%m  Mes, numérico (00..12)
%p  AM o PM
%r  Tiempo, 12-Hora (hh:mm:ss seguido de AM o PM)
%S  Segundos (00..59)
%s  Segundos (00..59)
%T  Tiempo, 24-Hora (hh:mm:ss)
%U  Semana (00..53), donde Domingo es el primer día de la semana; WEEK() mode 0
%u  Semana (00..53), donde Lunes es el primer día de la semana; WEEK() mode 1
%V  Semana (01..53), donde Domingo es el primer día de la semana; WEEK() mode 2; usado con %X
%v  Semana (01..53), donde Lunes es el primer día de la semana; WEEK() mode 3; usado con %x
%W  Nombre del día (Lunes...Domingo)
%w  Día de la semana (0=Domingo..6=Sábado)
%X  Año para la semana, donde Domingo es el primer día de la semana, numérico, 4 dígitos; usado con %V
%x  Año para la semana, donde Lunes es el primer día de la semana, numeric, 4 dígitos; usado con %v
%Y  Año, numérico, 4 dígitos
%y  Año, numérico (2 dígitos)
%%  Un literal “%” caracter
%x  x, para cualquier “x” que no se encuentre listado
```

Referencia: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html